# Angular : how to properly set multiple conditions with ngClass

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create my own UI library using angular and Tailwind, I am facing an issue using ngClass :

```html
  <button
    [ngClass]="{
      'px-4 py-2 text-sm': size === 'md',
      'px-4 py-2 text-base': size === 'lg',
    }"
  >
    My Button
  </button>
```

I want my class to be one of these above when the condition on the `size` is met.
The problem is when the `size` equals `'md'` and so the first condition is met : the class in the dom is only `text-sm` instead of `px-4 py-2 text-sm`

The ngClass documentations says :

> keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the
> value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed

My understanding is that in my example :

- The first condition is evaluated as true => the class is correctly being setup
- Then the second condition is evaluated as false => `px-4 py-2 text-base` is being removed from the class as so the only one remaining is `text-sm`.

I think I was able to understand the problem, but since I'm new to angular and I would like to learn how to use properly ngClass, does anyone have a solution to solve this ?

Comment: If your conditions are more complex than an if/else it would be better to place them in variables or functions in the `.ts` file of your component

Answer (score 1):

Add the common classes to your regular `class` attribute, like this:

```html
<button
    [ngClass]="{
      'text-sm': size === 'md',
      'text-base': size === 'lg',
    }"
   class="px-4 py-2"
  >
    My Button
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, do it like this with multiple conditions:

```
[ngClass]="property  === value1 ? 'css-class-name1' : property  === value2 ? 'css-class-name2' : property  === value3 ? 'css-class-name3' :   'default-css'"
```